# WPF Prism Entity Framework repository

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, prism, repository-pattern

I am building a WPF application using the PRISM guidance, I want to use the Entity Framework 4 for a data repository.
I have previously developed a Silverlight app, using Prism and WCF RIA Services which worked great as all my components are decoupled.

So what is the best way of getting data in my WPF application in a decoupled way.
Thanks for any advise

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look at the **BookLibrary** sample application of the **[WPF Application Framework (WAF)](http://waf.codeplex.com)**. It shows how to use the Entity Framework in a WPF MVVM application. However, it's not PRISM.